# Python retry code on psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: tuple concurrently updated

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a python script that makes a connection to a Postgres DB (no issues there) and asks for input to create a new role in the DB.  Occasionally, I will run into an issue where db connection succeeds, but the step of `cursor.execute(f"grant select on all tables in schema...")` fails due to the following db error `"psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: tuple concurrently updated"`

looking for a way to retry that line of code after some given time because the db usually clears itself of that issue.

Comment: thinking of try and except, just not sure to say wait 2 minutes then re-run that line of code

Comment: thinking using "sleep" for the pause

Comment: Perhaps https://pypi.org/project/retry2/

Comment: You should try to execute a retry procedure that will try to re-run `cursor.execute` after delay